# How to process 2 checkboxes in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms

```
         <td>Korting: <br>

                <input type="checkbox" name="student" value="15">Student 15%<br>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="senior" value="10">Senior 10%<br>
                 <input type="checkbox" name="klant" value="5">Klant 5%<br>
                <hr>
                </td>    
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" width="300px" name="submit" value="Bestellen">
                    <hr>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
        </table>
    <!--Shoppingcart eindigt hier-->
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){            

        $aantal = $_POST['aantal'][0];       

         echo "Aantal is: ".$aantal."<br>";            

 if(isset($_POST['student'])){

     $korting = 15;
     echo "Korting is $korting procent";
 }     if(isset($_POST['senior'])){

     $korting = 10;
     echo "Korting is $korting procent";
 }  if(isset($_POST['klant'])){

     $korting = 5;
     echo "Korting is $korting procent";
 }             
 }    

 ?>

</body>
```

When I select 2 checkboxes, I want the discounts to be summed.
For example: When I select Student and Senior, I want the echo text to be 25, instead of 15 and 10 separate. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting your `$korting` variable to some value for each value of "student", try adding the correct amount for each possible posted value:

```
//...
$korting = 0;
if(isset($_POST['student'])) {
    $korting += 15;
}

if(isset($_POST['senior'])){
    $korting += 10;
}

if(isset($_POST['klant'])){
    $korting += 5;
}             
echo "Korting is $korting procent";
//...
```

Comment: If two checkboxes are selected, both values will be set in the $_POST array, so both if() conditions will be true and $korting will be increased twice.